# Java 7 - Files.copy copying empty file

Tags: java

Files.copy is not working as expected. The copied file is always 0 bytes. 
Below is the code snippet

```
File sourceFile = new File(sorceFileName);
File destinationFile = new File(destinationFileName);
Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(), destinationFile.toPath());
```

What is the reason for this? Running on Solaris OS.

Comment: Does `sourceFile` contain anything?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Yes it does.

Comment: Unrelated note: you can use `Paths.get(sorceFileName)` to get a Path object instead of using the java.io.File class which has become a legacy API.

Comment: is it throwing an exception?

Comment: And no errors at all? That is doubtful

Comment: @user3507385 Have a read of my answer and if it satisfies your question put a tick besides it and if it doesn't kindly put a comment below it

Answer (score 1):

If the target file already exists, you'll need to specify that you want it replaced

```
Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(), destinationFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

You haven't posted any stack trace, but if you don't add the above `CopyOption` and the target file does exist, you will get a `FileAlreadyExistsException`, as described in the [comments by @fge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916693/java-7-files-copy-copying-empty-file/22916898#comment34978327_22916898) and in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29).

Comment: Should add that if the file already exists, you get, oh surprise, a `FileAlreadyExistsException` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to add one more attribute `REPLACE_EXISTING`

Like this: `Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);`
which in your case should be: `Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(), destinationFile.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Have a read of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html I hope it will help. If you want to know other ways to copy files you may want to read [this](http://www.journaldev.com/861/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-file-in-java/).

Comment: No difference. Same result.

Comment: @user3507385 Well that looks strange, do you get any errors? Is your file for sure not empty? Do you have the power to copy?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a huge bug in Solaris' filesystem, which I seriously doubt, your scenario is only possible if the source file is actually empty.

Since you say it isn't, then the API must have thrown an exception and you don't tell. Possible exceptions are:

- `FileAlreadyExistsException`: target file already exists; use solution provided in other posts;
- `AccessDeniedException`: meh, can't read source/write destination (many possible causes);
- `NoSuchFileException`: path in destination file contains one path element which does not exist;
- `FileSystemLoopException`: somewhere in the destination path is a symlink which loops on itself.

And of course the classical `IOException` and critical `IOError`...

Also, since you generate `Path`s from `File` objects, you can have `InvalidPathException`; unlike `File`, you *cannot* create `Path` objects from strings containing character sequences unmappable in your current encoding (not with the provided default `FileSystem` implementations at least).

You HAVE to have an exception somewhere...